# php parsing comma separated list of var=value pairs

Tags: php

I'm receiving a string

```
a=100,b=20,c=20;
```

for instance I know exploding this into an array using , as delimiter,
and it becomes

```
a=100
b=20
c=20
```

as strings,

how can this be further evaluated as variables inside php so I could do

```
echo $a //100
echo $b //20
echo $c //20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the function "parse_str"，like

```
$str = str_replace(','，'&',"a=100,b=10,c=20");
parse_str($str);
echo $a;
echo $b;
echo $c;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'a=1,b=20,c=43';
foreach ( explode(',', $string) as $expression ) {
    list($variable,$value) = explode('=', $expression);
    $$variable = $value;
}
echo 'a = ', $a, ' and b = ', $b, ' and c = ', $c, PHP_EOL;
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Depends how "dangerous" you want everything to be - you can always use [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) but then there are many issues to take into consideration.

Example:

```
eval("\$str = \"test\";");
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$input = 'a=100,b=20,c=20';
$items = explode(',',$input);

foreach($items as $i){
  $pair = explode('=',$i);
  $$pair[0] = $pair[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = 'a=100,b=20,c=20';

$statements = explode (',', $input);

foreach ($statements as $s)
  eval ('$' . $s); // THIS IS EVIL!!!! TOO MANY SECURITY PROBLEMS


echo $a; // will output 100
echo $b; // will output 20
echo $c; // will output 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable names for variables. Take for example:

```
$var = 'var2';
$$var = 5;
echo $var2;
```

this echoes 5 to the command line.

`$var` evaluates to being `var2`, and `$var2` is set to 5.

Taking your code we can create this:

```
$string = 'a=100,b=20,c=20';
$array = explode(',',$string);
foreach($array as $element) {
     $temp = explode('=',$element);
     $$temp[0] = $temp1;
}
echo $a.' '.$b.' '.$c;
```

This echoes the string '100 20 20'.